# Android layout qualifier usage

Tags: android, layout

Working and learning at the same time to use Android, I have noticed some weird/unexpected/not-so-documented behaviour from its layout switching functionality, for which I have not found an answer yet.

First, as the documentation suggests, qualifiers for width and height, such as `layout-w320dp` and `layout-h320p`should use the "standard" values - 240, 320, 480, 600 and so on. While the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) also mentions that the effectively available space is taken into account, it makes no further mention as to how this affects height. For example, by calling `getResources().getConfiguration().screenHeightDp` on a 320dp large emulator screen, the available height returned is 295. Thus, using `layout-h320p` is inaccurate, as it will not "activate" properly on a 320dp screen.

The stuff which I am writing, in what concerns adapting to small screens has (should have) the capability of handling two scenarios: one where there is not enough width, and one where there is not enough height. What I have found is that I cannot force the emulator to choose the correct layout for my situation: I have a folder for `layout-w320p` and another for `layout-h240p`. When running on a emulator with 320p available height and 480p available width, the `layout-w320p` loads. How can one homogeneously treat such two cases? One cannot specify both a width and a height qualifier.

Third, since if one wants to support one's app until 2.2, is there any way to support different screens except by the means of "classical" qualifiers (small, medium, large, x-large) ?

Edit: I've resorted to using the small/medium/large/xlarge qualifier pattern, since the minimum version I want to support is 2.2. I also use the `port` and `land` qualifiers, and Android's decision making in layouts is much more clear this way, but the aforementioned issues remain.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you haven't considered you ca combine two or more qualifiers? For example you can write layout-w320p-h240p making a layout 320x240